# Finding matching columns values based upon hostname

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join

I have a table `table1` with `b_id` as `PK`,  `ip`, `host`
In this table different hosts can have the same ipaddress
Here, `t2_id` is foreign key to `id` of `table2`

```
b_id    ip              host             t2_id
9205    10.10.10.10     zero             1121
9206    10.10.10.10     hello.abc.com    1121
9207    10.10.10.10     hi.abc.com       1121
```

I have another table `table2` `id` as `PK`,  `ip`, `host` and `b_id` Here `b_id` is Foreign key to `table1`
In my project, two hostname `hi.abc.com` and `hi` are considered as same because the domain name `abc.com` is not considered in comparison. So, I just need to compare the `hostname without domain name`

```
id      ip              host             b_id
1121    10.10.10.10     hi               null
```

I want to filter out rows from `table1` which have same `ip` values but the `host` is different
So, my output should be

```
b_id    ip              host             t2_id
9205    10.10.10.10     zero             1121
9206    10.10.10.10     hello.abc.com    1121
```

I have written following query but it is not giving correct result

```
select * from table1 T1 INNER JOIN table2 T2
ON T1.t2_id = T2.id
where T1.host not like T2.host;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `not exists`?

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.ip = t1.ip and
                        substring_index(t2.host, '.', 1) = substring_index(t1.host, '.', 1)
                 ) ;
```